# segment.io javascript publish fails with a CORS error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, segment-io

I'm encountering a cross origin resource sharing (CORS) error when I try to load a webpage with the sample "getting started" javascript code from the segment.io website. Below is the html itself.  I haven't set any headers on my play 2.1.3 server that's vending this page, but I assume that's not necessary because other users have assured me they have run this with no problems.:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.analytics=window.analytics||[],window.analytics.methods=["identify","group","track","page","pageview","alias","ready","on","once","off","trackLink","trackForm","trackClick","trackSubmit"],window.analytics.factory=function(t){return function(){var a=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);return a.unshift(t),window.analytics.push(a),window.analytics}};for(var i=0;i<window.analytics.methods.length;i++){var key=window.analytics.methods[i];window.analytics[key]=window.analytics.factory(key)}window.analytics.load=function(t){if(!document.getElementById("analytics-js")){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript",a.id="analytics-js",a.async=!0,a.src=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https://":"http://")+"cdn.segment.io/analytics.js/v1/"+t+"/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(a,n)}},window.analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="2.0.9",
window.analytics.load("**my_key_here**");
window.analytics.page();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load this page with my browser, I see the following errors on the javascript console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:9000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (p, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.segment.io/v1/p. Origin http://localhost:9000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (localhost, line 0)
```

Any ideas?  Even on the segment.io site, there's no mention that CORS should be an issue just to publish events with the javascript client.

Answer (score 9):

It could be a browser extension that blocks tracking scripts. Do you have one installed? For example, I was using [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/) on Chrome and was experiencing a similar error until I whitelisted my site.

The error I was seeing was `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.segment.io/v1/i. The request was redirected to a URL ('about:blank') which has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.`